# How to run code when clicking a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm aware that I can use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` but this doesn't do exactly what I want.

For example when I move the active cell with the arrow keys it will still run the code.

**How do I only make it run the code when actually physically clicking on the cell?**

Comment: There's right click and double click but no left click (that would be a nightmare XD)

Comment: So there's no way to use a cell as a button?

Comment: I was using activeX buttons before but they get messed up all the time so I'm looking for other options

Comment: If we know what you're trying to do, we might be able to suggest other solutions. Or ask a question to fix your current buttons?

Comment: @findwindow I'm using 2 kinds of buttons. 1 to hide/unhide some predefined rows. The other one just changing values of other cells with predefined values, but this one needs to work similar to a radio button.

Comment: There is a Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) event but that will fire until after a change has been made.

Comment: @MatthewD What kind of change is required? Isn't clicking the cell enough change? (Activecell value changes?)

Comment: Actually, testing it seems that it does fire on cell selection.

Comment: The buttons don't sound that complex. I would ask a new question to fix whatever issue you have with them.

Comment: @findwindow I have asked that question. The answer to that question basicly came down to "It's a bug in Excel, can't be fixed"

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564019/changing-cell-value-with-mouse-buttons-excel/23565221#23565221)

Comment: Here is the Windows stuff for keypress. You can record if an arrow key is pressed and the time. Then you could put a check at the begining of the  selectionchanged and exit if the last key pressed was an arrow within a fraction of a second. If that is true you will exit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153995/is-there-any-event-that-fires-when-keys-are-pressed-when-editing-a-cell

Comment: Yes, there is a bug / problem with ActiveX buttons which seem to get messed up from time to time. But this problem vanishes if you use ordinary form buttons. I removed all ActiveX buttons years ago and changed to from buttons and all problems disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left mouse click cannot be trapped with VBA for the Excel application. There are some methods to check globally if the left mouse button is pressed down but it does not seem simple and reliable from what I gather. See:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_28343702.html which is unresolved (basically the same question you have)

SelectionChange cannot only work for the mouse: http://excel.tips.net/T003070_Mouse_Click_Event_in_VBA.html

After lots of searching nothing on the web is conculsive about this. This may not be the answer you're looking for but I don't think you'll find what you want.

Comment: As for the lack of 'official' documentation... msdn is good for what IS implemented in VBA but doesn't state what cannot be done.

Comment: Alright. thank you for the effort. I guess selectionChange is gonna have to do then.

Comment: @JentevanHeuverswyn well this isn't true. Check out my answer to a similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564019/changing-cell-value-with-mouse-buttons-excel/23565221#23565221)

Comment: @EngJon NICE! That's a revelation. I get a compilation error when trying it out but if you can make it work for him I will delete as soon as he sees your comment. If you post your answer, I will delete mine.

Comment: It seems like your initial solution was unresolved in the end from the comments underneath it. Was he eventually able to make it work as intended? I need to know this for personal use as well :D

Comment: @DavidG What is your compilation error? It may be solved by [this](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/983043)

Answer (score 3):

You can detect left clicks as well. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564019/changing-cell-value-with-mouse-buttons-excel/23565221#23565221)

Insert the following code inside the specific worksheet module (for example "Sheet1"):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLButton)) Then 'left mouse button
            'do something here
    End If
End Sub
```

additionally, you have to insert the following part on the top of a normal module (like the standard "Module1"):

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
```

That's it. The part "do something here" can be filled by your needs.

However, this has some flaws: If you do something that finishes with a click (e.g. a MsgBox), the next selection change with arrow keys will also fire the event and re-execute your stuff. To bypass this, you can add an extra "empty"

`If (GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLButton)) Then 'left mouse button
    'blank
End If`

in the end of the selectionChange Sub. As I said, there are flaw**s**, so this won't disable all unwanted behaviour by Excel. Another one is clicking somewhere else in Excel (e.g. choosing another ribbon) and changing the selection of cells per arrow keys afterwards. Haven't found a solution to that one unfortunately.

Comment: Tried this but couldn't get this to work. No errors, but nothing happening either

Comment: You have to make sure everything is in the right place. The worksheet_selectionchange has to be in the module of the sheet you are trying it on, not "this workbook". And the declare command has to be placed in a normal module (like module1 if you insert one).

Comment: Double checked and triple checked. Everything is in the right place

Comment: If you skip the key check, does the selection change work as it should?

Comment: @JentevanHeuverswyn And I assume you exchanged `do something here` with actual code? Just asking